# Importing CSV into Kibana and mapping geo_point

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, mapping, kibana, geopoints

I'm using ES/Kibana 7.5. and I have the following CSV file with 3 columns.; first_seen, last_seen and geom.

[Dropbox link to the CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mwkvvdw3c3mol0/test.csv)

Type of the first 2 columns are date and the 3d column, "geom" is geo_point with valid POINT (lon lat) format according to the [ES document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html).

[Screenshot of CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQYWc.png)

Issue is, when I import this test.csv file into the Kibana, in Advanced tab, in the mapping section, Kibana recognizes the "geom" column as keyword.

Then I re-write/change the type to geo_point as shown below:

[image of mapping fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcQuv.png)

But upon import I get the following error and end up with empty fields:

0: failed to parse field [geom] of type [geo_point]

How can I get ES/Kibana to recognize/map "geom" column as geo_point?